# Connection between Java program and website

Tags: java, mysql, web

I'm still new to java programming and web application development, though I just want to ask is it possible to create a java program and a website that has a single database(most preferably phpmyadmin) meaning the java program and the website are more likely connected through the use of this particular database. If what I'm suggesting is not possible then is their a way to create a java program that is directly connected to the website?

Comment: So your question is: can a Java application and a web site access the same database? The answer is yes, obviously. Note that phpmyadmin is not a database. MySQL is a database. phpmyadmin is a web application allowing to browse and query MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to create a java program and a website that has a
>   single database

yes, your Web-database-server should be configured to allowe remote connections
but this is not recommended due to security issues.

alternative: using web services

> most preferably phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin is just a grafical web user interface which enables the admin of a Database to manage SQL Services

Comment: I get it. so can I make a java program which inputs the information of a client then I want that information to go directly to the site in order for people to see it?

Comment: yes, web server should implement a web service i.e. (java-ws + SOAP + CXF), from the WSDL-File of this service, in your App Project, you can generate  the WS-Client, you can use these generated classes in your App and connect to web server. there are many tutorials on the net on how to do it.